# Using functions in C++ (void, double, int)

Tags: c++, function, void

I am slowly trying to learn c++ on my own and got stuck using functions. I did find a way to get past the initial problem but I have no idea why I couldn't do it the way I first intended to. Here's the working program.

```
// ex 6, ch 2
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

void time(int, int);
int main() 
{
int h, m; 
cout << "Enter the number of hours: "; 
cin >> h; 
cout << endl; 
cout << "Enter the number of minutes: "; 
cin >> m; 
cout << endl; 
time(h, m); 

cin.get();
cin.get();
return 0; 
} 

void time(int hr, int mn)
{
 cout << "The time is " << hr << ":" << mn;  
}
```

And here is how I would like to do it.

```
// ex 6, ch 2
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

void time(int, int);
int main() 
{
int h, m; 
cout << "Enter the number of hours: "; 
cin >> h; 
cout << endl; 
cout << "Enter the number of minutes: "; 
cin >> m; 
cout << endl; 
cout << "The time is " << time(h, m); 

cin.get();
cin.get();
return 0; 
} 

void time(int hr, int mn)
{
 cout << hr << ":" << mn;  
}
```

In my head both of them would return the same thing but my compiler thinks otherwise (and I would like to know why).

Edit: It seems to work like this for some odd reason.

```
cout << "The time is "; 
time(h, m);
```

If nothing more, it just made me more confused.

Answer (score 3):

```
cout << "The time is " << time(h, m);
```

`time` does not return anything, but to send something to `cout` in this case would require it to return a value (probably a string in this case) vs having the `time` function call `cout` directly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your `time`-function to return a `string`. I'm using `stringstream` to convert int to string.

```
#include <sstream>
...
string time(int, int);

...

string time(int hr, int mn)
{
    stringstream sstm;
    sstm << hr << ":" << mn;
    string result = sstm.str();
    return result;
}
```

Now you can use it directly, like:

```
cout << "The time is " << time(h, m);
```

Comment: Tried the changing it to string. For some reason it didn't return anything. (No compiling errors, though). Also, the description of the exercise said that I should use a void function for the function call.

Comment: Have you remembered to edit the declaration in the header? See my edit

Comment: Yeah. Did that. No results. The program runs perfectly but when it's supposed to print out the line
     cout << "The time is " << time(h, m);
it just leaves the time(h,m) part empty.

Comment: I'm sorry, silly of me. You cant convert int to stirng like that, you can for example use a `stringstream`. I'll show you

Comment: This is actually the first time I've ever used stringstreams but I'll keep it in mind as an option.

Are there any ways of doing it with a void function as well? This is the exercise I started with "Write a program that asks the user to enter an hour value and a minute value.The
main() function should then pass these two values to a type void function that displays
the two values in the format shown in the following sample run"

Comment: Well that sounds a lot like what you have in your first code block, above. For what you are trying to do in the second, my code will do the job.

Comment: Just figured out how to make the second way work as well. Edited my first post. Any idea why it works?

Comment: Aren't you doing the same as in your first example? The difference is: calling `cout << "The time is " << time(h, m);` required the `time`-function to return a string. Just doing: `cout << "The time is "; time(h, m);` Is the same you your doing, but just not ending the line before printing the time

Comment: I am slightly confused now. So.. it seems to be working fine if I don't include the function call in the `cout << "The time is "; time(h, m);` because it doesn't require it to return a string? Or am I following the wrong logic here? The edit seems to be the same thing I did in the first example, yeah. I know this might sound a bit cheeky but do you have skype or something I could use to talk with you? Just to make it more instant (read: without the waiting time in between responses).